# How to login using login command with password and user name in one line

Tags: command-line, login

I want to make a login using login command with password and username in one line. I've tried the `echo password | sudo -S login user` but this doesn't work. Is there any other way to login with password and user name in one command?

Comment: why do you want to do it? I assume that you understand that `echo password` is not recommended from security point of view.

Comment: then how does display managers like lightdm and gdm works

Comment: What are you trying to solve?